How to load a model from uncompressed ZIP64 archive on PyTorch
due to some bugs on the cloud platform I use to train a model, I can only download the trained model in a folder structure like below;
checkpoint
├── data.pkl
├── byteorder # added in PyTorch 2.1.0
├── data/
│ ├── 0
│ ├── 1
│ ├── 2
│ └── …
└── version
But i couldn't understand from this documentation how to load this checkpoint as a state dict. I want to use in the end;
model.load_state_dict(checkpoint)

I tried passing the .pkl file to the function, but it doesn't work. So, can somebody help me what's the correct way to do it?
